# Rewrite .html extension to .mqn with .htaccess on a Linux server?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

<strike>Hello. We all know that the .mqn does not exist. But I want to make my friends believe it does.</strike>

What I want here is to change the .html extension to display .mqn in the omnibox. When a user enters, I want index.html to be displayed as index.mqn.

I have the following code in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.mqn
```

With this code, when someone enters index.mqn, they can see index.html with the .mqn address displayed in the omnibox.

But the thing I want is, also, when someone enters index.html, that index.mqn be displayed in the bar.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: every file extension (file name) exists

Comment: you need to a client-side redirect. what you have is purely an internal-rewrite. e.g. `Rewrite ... [R=301,L]`

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.mqn
```

> With this code, when someone enters index.mqn, they can see index.html
>   with the .mqn address displayed in the omnibox.

That code above does not do what you say it does. That internal rewrites to `.mqn` and will display the `.html` file in the omnibox. Which will probably give you a 404.

What it seems like you want is the opposite. You want to display the .`mqn` files in the omnibox. You should be able to use these rules in your .htaccess file. This should redirect any one who enters a .html file in the omnibox as well as make it *appear* that .mqn is a `real` file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} [A-Z]{3,}\ /(.+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.mqn? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.mqn$ $1.html [L]
```

Comment: Provide an example URL you want to use in the browser. Also **what** didn't work?

Comment: It resulted in a permanent 301 redirect and when I opened index.mqn nothing happened. Even after removing the code from .htaccess, html files stopped opening and display a 404 error.

Comment: Your rules are probably cached. Clear your browser cache  and then add my rules or try in another browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect user there, add [R] flag to your rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.mqn [R]
```